# What is the best model for time series data with independent and dependent variables

Tags: r, time-series, vector-autoregression

I have two different variables across a time series over a couple thousand time steps.  I want to predict the values of the dependent variable (y) based values of the independent variable (x) in the future.  I have been using a VAR model in R from the vars package.  The problem here seems to be that the VAR model predicts both x and y and treats the future time steps as the independent variable.  What is the appropriate model or method to use predict y in the future given x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the [vars package vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf) describes Impulse / Response Analysis as the last step. This sounds like what you are looking for.  They end with unemployment predicted by the other variables with the command:

```
svec.irf <- irf(svec, response = "U", n.ahead = 48, boot = TRUE)
```

"irf" is an acronym for Impulse Response Function.

There is also a [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) with a general introduction for several disciplines.  My guess is that the one on Economics might be closest to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to predict y given x. For instance, you can use ARIMAX model. You can fit a transfer function with x. Transfer function is a parsimonious way to transmit changes in an independent to a dependent variable. It is a complex problem to identify the transfer function. You can implement this model in most statistical software such as R and SAS.